# limit outbound access for an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, firewall, routing

Our company is in the process to become PCI compliant and one of the requirement is to limit the outbound access of our servers.
We have only 1 EC2 instance that falls in the PCI scope and I would like to limit outbound internet access to this instance to only the services needed.

Is there anyway to build that? Is a VPC the best option to do it?

Thanks a lot,

Elie

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

- **Security Groups** allow you to choose CIDR (ip range) and port. You can restrict outbound access at the Instance level.
- **Network ACLs** allow you to do the same, but at the Subnet level.
- You can place a **firewall** into your network or utilise your **NAT device**, to control outbound access.  This can help with logging which may be a requirement for PCI compliance.
- You could employ software firewalls, like iptables for linux which can also assist with logging requirements.

Answer (score 0):

VPC gives you control of out going traffic via security group of that particular box. If "built that" means controlling access via code then I use python boto to do things programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. When I try to edit my security group in EC2 I can only see inbound traffic nothing for the outbound traffic

Comment: I updated my answer, please take a look again.

Comment: So if I want to restrict outbound access I have to use a VPC?

Comment: VPC allows you to control out bound access through security groups. If you want to control out bound traffic in EC2 I think you would have to use system level firewall ( I haven't used ec2 based system firewall myself)

Comment: Security Groups control both inbound and outbound access on an EC2.